Repeated matches with a start anchor in regexp_matches()
I need to get all biggest digit sequences from a string with the requirement that the whole string should not start with 'a'.
Each result should be a separate entry in the result set.
Just to clarify, regexp_matches() returns a result set containing arrays with only one element if no capturing parentheses are present in the pattern.
The result set is formed by consecutive matches of the same pattern in the same string, starting the next match where the previous match ended.
If it wasn't a required that the string cannot start with an a, an example that would fulfil the request would be:
select regexp_matches('bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu','\d+','gi');

the above would result in a record set below:
"{45456}"
"{888}"
"{89776}"

Is there a way to implement the requirement to have matches only if the whole string does not start with a?

Only if it could support unlimited width lookbehind  patterns like (?<!^a.*)\d+

I am trying to find it and I think there may be a way to do it

@WiktorStribiżew If only.

Wondering if you could use The Trick here. If you normally match the part you don't want but use capturing parentheses for the parts you do want: SELECT regexp_matches('bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu', '^a.*|(\d+)', 'gi') ... however it would return NULL if the left side of the alternation matched (starting with an a) which can be undesired.

@bobblebubble You can. Regexp_matches() is an SRF, so its natural place is actually not the SELECT list but he FROM list, where it's joined with. You can define that JOIN explicitly to disallow the match on (^a.*): demo.

@bobblebubble You're welcome to post it as your own. You suggested the pattern, I just pointed out the SRF thing.

@GeorgeKourtis If my and @Zegarek's comment also help, feel encouraged too integrate it into your own answer, or Zegarek into his answer! I won't put another one.

Assuming a is undesired right in front of the match, not the whole thing, you can use POSIX regex negative lookbehind syntax to get all matches of \d+, except those with an a up front - as hinted by @Wiktor Stribiżew. Demo at db<>fiddle:
create table test(sample,comment)as values
  ('bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu','no digits with an `a` up front'),
  ('abax 45456xx888z 89776uuu','`a` before everything'),
  ('bax a45456xxa888z 89776uuu','the first 2 digit sequences have a leading `a`, none up front');

select * from test
cross join lateral regexp_matches(sample,'((?<!a\d*)\d+)','gi');




sample
comment
regexp_matches




bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
no digits with an `a` up front
{45456}


bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
no digits with an `a` up front
{888}


bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
no digits with an `a` up front
{89776}


abax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
`a` before everything
{45456}


abax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
`a` before everything
{888}


abax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
`a` before everything
{89776}


bax a45456xxa888z 89776uuu
the first 2 digit sequences have a leading `a`, none up front
{89776}




If you want to only avoid strings with an a at the very beginning of the whole thing, tolerating ones right in front of the individual strings of digits, @Wiktor's pattern nailed that already:
select * from test
cross join lateral regexp_matches(sample,'(?<!^a.*)\d+','gi');




sample
comment
regexp_matches




bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
no digits with an `a` up front
{45456}


bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
no digits with an `a` up front
{888}


bax 45456xx888z 89776uuu
no digits with an `a` up front
{89776}


bax a45456xxa888z 89776uuu
the first 2 digit sequences have a leading `a`, none up front
{45456}


bax a45456xxa888z 89776uuu
the first 2 digit sequences have a leading `a`, none up front
{888}


bax a45456xxa888z 89776uuu
the first 2 digit sequences have a leading `a`, none up front
{89776}



An alternative approach would be to catch both the undesired and the desired pattern into separate groups, then only returning hits where undesired pattern with leading a wasn't found (its group was empty), as per The Trick suggested by @bobble bubble:
select test.*,m[2] from test
inner join lateral regexp_matches(sample,'(^a.*)|(\d+)','gi')m on m[1] is null;


The request is that the whole string should not start with 'a' and not that the number should not be preceded by the letter a, I suppose your answer resolves the second case not the first

@WiktorStribiżew Marvelous it does work !

The only solution I found is the bellow:
regexp_matches((regexp_matches('A a45456xxa888z a89776','^[^a].*','i'))[1],'\d+','g');

The problem is that there is no full search for '*' but only greedy or lazy versions of it.
If there was a 'full' match version using e.g. '¿' than the solution would had been:
select regexp_matches('caA a45456xxa888z a89776','^(?:[^a])\D*(?:\d+\D+)*¿(\d+)','i');


I understand that Postgres PL/Perl enables the user to write PostgreSQL functions and procedures in the Perl programming language. If that is done one can match the regular expression
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?!a))\D*\K\d+

Demo
The expression can be broken down as follows.
(?:       # begin non-capture group
  \G      # assert position to be at the end of the previous match   
  (?!^)   # negative lookahead asserts current position is not
          # the beginning of the string
  |       # or
  ^       # match the beginning of the string
  (?!a)   # negative lookahead asserts next char is not 'a'
)         # end non-capture group
\D*       # match zero or more chars other than digits, as many as possible 
\K        # reset the start of the match and discard all matched chars
\d+       # match one or more digits, as many as possible

Please note an alternative regular expression given in the comments.

If PCRE could be used, another option with verbs: ^a.*(*SKIP)(*F)|\d+
